# Is "Unneeded" as standard as "Unnecessary"?

Tags: word-choice, non-standard

The word "Unneeded" is a lot rarer than "Unnecessary", according to [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unneeded%2Cunnecessary&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cunneeded%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bunneeded%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUnneeded%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunnecessary%3B%2Cc0). The word "Unneeded" has also been used [less in older times](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unneeded&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cunneeded%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bunneeded%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUnneeded%3B%2Cc0) than current times, which would be consistent with it being a non-standard word.

[oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/unneeded) and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unneeded) have definitions for "Unneeded", and don't describe it as non-standard. But I'm not certain that it is standard English.

Are people likely to regard "Unneeded" as non-standard, or as a newspeak style neologism based on combining "un" with "needed" by someone who doesn't know how to spell "Unnecessary"?

Comment: It is unnecessary to wonder if every word you use is "non-standard", since there is no "standard".  And, no, it is not true that "unneeded" is unneeded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right that "unnecessary" is used more than "unneeded": the google reports a 20:1 advantage for the former.  But that's still over 5M hits for the latter, hardly a usage that most people would regard as "non-standard."  (By which I term I take it you mean a word so close to obsolescence that native speakers would almost never use it and find it distractingly quaint when they heard others do so.)

I think most readers fluent in English would understand that the phrase "**unneeded** organs" in a news article would refer to transplant doctors' fervent hope that one day enough people would volunteer to be organ donors after their deaths that there would be a surplus of such organs available for transplant.  So many that sometimes the docs couldn't use them all.

On the other hand, those same readers would understand that the phrase "**unnecessary** organs" would refer to useless bodily structures that evolution has bequeathed us.  You know, like the epoophoron.

The two words are not quite interchangeable.